# Athena Schema creation when log format has missing fields

Tags: amazon-athena

I have a custom log format where the log entries vary by the request type. So certain rows have more fields.

Can we specify certain fields as optional so that in rows that they are missing, the values will be set to certain default (null, 0)?

Here are some hypothetical log entries:

`{"data":"[2017-09-10 10:44:54.448998 -0000] info ip=773.555.557.445 cluster=\"production\" query=uris type=TXT class=IN rcode=NXDOMAIN cnt=0 offset=74","header":{"recvtime":"2017-09-10 10:45:02","server":"m0107481","refid":"ABC-123"}}`

`{"data":"[2017-09-10 10:44:54.457718 -0000] info ip=991.509.704.832 cluster=\"inbound\" query=dnsbl type=A class=IN rcode=NOERROR cnt=1 offset=90 score=400","header":{"recvtime":"2017-09-10 10:45:02","server":"m010748","refid":"ABC-123"}}`

`{"data":"[2017-09-10 10:44:54.457718 -0000] info ip=971.509.704.832 cluster=\"inbound\" query=dnsbl type=A class=IN rcode=REFUSED cnt=1","header":{"recvtime":"2017-09-10 10:45:02","server":"m010574","refid":"ABC-123"}}`

Note that each row of the log data is in json format, and the header part is fixed. If query in data is dnsbl, then sometimes the row has a score field, but other times it is missing. And I am planning to use Athena to parse this type of data from S3 and query for some stats in the line of: what % of data are dns queries and what % have score above 300.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your data is JSON with embedded structured logging in the `data` field. As long as the data is well formed JSON with one object per line you should be able to create a JSON table and then use functions to extract the other pieces out of the `data` field. You can create a view that does the extraction so that you don't have to do that in every query.

I'm thinking something like this:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE raw_log_entries (
  data string,
  header struct<recvtime: string, server: string, refid: string>
)   
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe'
LOCATION 's3://some-bucket/and/path/';
```

```
CREATE VIEW log_entries AS
SELECT
  header.recvtime,
  header.server,
  header.refid,
  regexp_extract(data, 'query=(\S+)', 1) AS query,
  regexp_extract(data, 'type=(\S+)', 1) AS type,
  regexp_extract(data, 'score=(\S+)', 1) AS score,
  -- and so on
FROM raw_log_entries
```

You'll have to experiment with the regexes, since I don't have your data I can't be sure if they will work for all cases, but I hope you get the idea.